# Register Javascript reply from JXA

Tags: javascript, macos, javascript-automation

Back again with a JavaScipt / JXA question. I'm trying to register a response from a application that I'm calling with JXA. I am trying to register the value `app.toDos.byId("HQebK1em72yZqc3WqTmyzx")`. When I kick of the following script:

```js
var TaskApp = Application('Things3')

var toDo = TaskApp.ToDo({
  name: "A new task",
  notes: "notes"
})

var newTask = TaskApp.toDos.push(toDo)

console.log("Task " + newTask)
```

I get the following output in the Replies field:

```js
app = Application("Things")
    Application("Things").toDos.push(app.ToDo({"name":"A new task", "notes":"notes"}))
        --> app.toDos.byId("HQebK1em72yZqc3WqTmyzx")
    Application("Things").toDos.length
        --> 3502

/* Task 3502 */
Result:
undefined
```

This looks like this in the editor:
[image]

The value `newTask` seems to be overwritten by the `.push` method which returns the array length. Can I somehow register or return the new task ID that is returned by the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is expected: `push` is a JavaScript standard library method that [always returns the array length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push). Just do this instead:

```js
var TaskApp = Application('Things3')

var toDo = TaskApp.ToDo({
  name: "A new task",
  notes: "notes"
})

TaskApp.toDos.push(toDo)

console.log("Task " + toDo.id())
```

Comment: This solution produces the desired result. Clear explanation of the behaviour. Thank you for the top notch answer (: